# adding static time interval panel in Grafana Prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

I am trying to add a static panel to show total number of request for the current year in grafana prometheus

I am using sum(http_server_requests_seconds_count{}) for the current interval selection in grafana

Is any way i can do that for current year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1y])`. But it's not going to be fast. Or easy on Prometheus. Also, make sure you're using it as instant query (the *Instant* switch below the query textarea) or it's going to be even worse.